# How to grep a file and output the matching part of a line plus a few surrounding words?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, grep

I am searching a file for a pattern and would like to limit the output so that it does not display the whole line, but a match surrounded by a few words, so I can see the context. The lines are too long to comfortably view the whole line in the output. I'm looking for a solution with grep, awk, and/or sed. grep has `-o` option, and it might be possible to use that if I have the right regular expression for that.

As an extra feature, it would be nice if the solution would optionally support grep's line number feature, so that line numbers could be printed along with the output when desired.

**UPDATE:**
Here is a test file:

```
1 2 3 4 5 abc 1 2 3 4
abc
1 2 abc
abc 1
1 abc 1
1 2 3 abc 1 2 3
1 2 3 4 abc 1
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3
1
```

**SOLUTION:**

Changing the number of minimum words to zero, so that we do not miss matches of keyword not surrounded by any words:

```
egrep -no '(\w+ ){0,3}keyword( \w+){0,2}' file
```

Example:

```
egrep -no '(\w+ ){0,3}abc( \w+){0,2}' test.txt
```

Output:

```
1:3 4 5 abc 1 2
2:abc
3:1 2 abc
4:abc 1
5:1 abc 1
6:1 2 3 abc 1 2
7:2 3 4 abc 1
```

Comment: You need provide detail sample files and do the explanation on the expect output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like:

```
egrep -no '(\w+ ){1,3}keyword( \w+){1,2}' file
```

This will print lines containing the word 'keyword' with a line number prefix. It will print up to three words before the match and up to two words after the match.

`\w` will match any single character classified as a "word" character (alphanumeric or `_`).

This answer also assumes words a separated by a single space character.